# ios: Include Tabbar like control inside one ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just wanted to include multiple views inside one viewcontroller. I may use Tabbar controller. But What I need is ... I have one parent viewcontroller and I want to load different "form" inside that view controller. Please refer the images.. [image]

[image]

Kindly provide me the best way to accomplish it...

I am using xib not storyboards. Will I need to design both item1 and item2 in that single xib?

Comment: you also use segment controller as par you screenshot i guess you can use else you can also used PageViewController.

Comment: Actually In previous projects, I just designed both forms inside that xib. By pressing button I perform show/hide the views. Is there any other simple way to implement this?

Comment: Thanks @NitinGohel, I will search about SegmentController. Can u provide me any samples for this. It would be very helpful

Comment: find here you get lots of exmple code: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=segment

Comment: Thanks @NitinGohel,  It has lot of good examples which I need exactly ...